# Unable To Recover URL Stored in MySQL database

Tags: java, url, jdbc, resultset, data-linking

I am writing an application that stores profile images of users in a mysql database, due to performance set backs brought about by BLOB and CLOB data types, I have resolved not to use them, but to store the image url in the database table as varchar values.

Here is the problem: When I try to retrive the url using ResultSet.getURL() method or even  resultSet.getString(). I get a MalformedURLException- "Protocol :C not recognised". How do I solve this please help.

Here is my code;

```
 try {
        sqlConnectionObject = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,"root","");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Androbot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter fileFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("pic", "jpg");
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(fileFilter);

    obtainURLFromDBButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, obtainImageUrl("userName"));
                File file = new File(obtainImageUrl("userName").toString()); //the obtain image url 
                                                                             //function is called  here
                                                                             //and passed to File
                                                                             //file is used to creat image
                Image img = ImageIO.read(file);
                thisButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    );

//Allows user to set profile
    addImagButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Add Profile Picture");
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                // fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                try {
                    // file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\EmmaBeib\\12553040_133350150376029_4407158756206009973_n.jpg");
                    String fileUrl = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"URL = "+fileUrl);
                    addURLRow("userName", fileUrl);
                    image = ImageIO.read(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());

                    addImagButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                  //  addPictureToDB(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }catch(SQLException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR"+e.getMessage());
                }

            } else if (ret == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Apopprove cancel?", "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (opt == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Add Profile Picture");
                }
            } else if (ret == JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An ERROR occured try again later");

            }
        }
    }
    );

//Obtain picture from the database
public Object obtainImageUrl(String userName) throws MalformedURLException {
    try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/picturedb", "root", "")) {
        Statement mysqlStm = connect.createStatement();
        String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM picture WHERE userName IN ('" + userName + "');";
        ResultSet cursor = mysqlStm.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        while (cursor.next()) {
            imageUrl = cursor.getObject("picUrl");
        }
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl.toString());
        // File imageFile = new File(imageUrl);
        try {
            Image img = ImageIO.read(url);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return imageUrl;
}
 //insert image url in the db
public void addPictureToDB(File file) {
    imageUrl = file.getAbsolutePath();
    try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "root", "")) {
        Statement mysqlStmt = connect.createStatement();
        String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO picture VALUES('"
                + imageUrl + "','"
                + "BETTY KIPPO');";
        mysqlStmt.execute(INSERT_QUERY);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Added Succefully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that you are storing the location of a file as an absolute path for a local file, e.g., `C:\folder\...`. If so, then you probably shouldn't think of them as URLs, just store them in the database as VARCHAR and work with them as String values.

Comment: ... also, you should read up on using `PreparedStatement` objects and *parameterized queries* to replace the dynamic SQL in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through research and Experimentation, my findings are that when I use the

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath().toString();
```

That way the path string sent to the database is valid url and I therefore need not to change the protocol am using onRetrieve.

Comment: File chooser give you the actual file path in string representation